# Geographically weighted regression with QGIS / R / etc?

Tags: qgis, r, geographically-weighted-regression

I have a small project where I'd like to investigate the relationship between number of events (many thousand x-y points) in a city and the rent of each neighbourhood (around 50 x-y centroid points of neighbourhood polygons, each with a corresponding rent value).

I have these two data sets in two csvs (one with all the events and their lat/long, the other with all the neighbourhood centroids and their rent value).

I was hoping I would be able to click some kind of magic button in QGIS to do a geographically weighted regression (I already did a basic non-GW regression and plot in R and there was a nice relationship) in order to account for the proximity of the actual points for events/neighbourhoods... but I can't see an option anywhere in the menu for GWR.

Therefore,

1) Is there a way to do this easily in QGIS? Perhaps a plugin of some sort?

2) If not, do I have to use R and what is the plugin for this?

I've never done GWR before.

Comment: You can use R scripts in the Processing Toolbox

Comment: Ah yes thanks - is there one you suggest for basic GWR?

Comment: You need a solution in R first and after, create the script ( example in [Integrating QGIS and R: A stratified sampling example](http://amsantac.co/blog/en/2015/10/31/qgis-r.html) and [QGIS-Processing rscripts](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/tree/master/rscripts))

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question do it sounds like you should focus this on R and if you get stuck on QGIS later then ask about that then in a separate question.

Comment: Please note that your neighborhoods represent areas, which may vary considerably in size, and cannot be treated as a discrete point feature. This is statistically invalid because a point does not represent the polygon area and the inference derived from the model would thus be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the standalone GWR4 app?  It was developed by Fotheringham et al.  It seems that it is missing a permanent home on the web right now, but I found this link:  https://gwrtools.github.io/gwr4-downloads.html

Edit:  The application is outside of QGIS and R but will accept CSV format as input.  The outputs are a .txt file with summary information and a .csv file with local estimates for all of your points.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please [edit] your answer to include some information about what your suggestion does, and how to use it in order to answer the question.